# Symbolising point shapefile in QGIS: half blue half red colored point

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, symbology, geometry-generator

I have a point shapefile. I have one point which I want in two colors. One half should be blue, the other one red. It should be divided vertically.

I tried the gradient version but it is as it says a gradient and I dont want that. I think next to the fill color is an epsilon where you can put an expression. Does somebody know the expression for diving the point vertically in to two colors?

Comment: Which GIS software do you use?

Comment: what software are you using?

Comment: QGIS. I think I found a solution. You can do two half a circle and then rotate them 90° and 270°. But if someone has another answer I would also appreciate that:)

Comment: @Lina Yours seems like the most straightforward solution imo.

Comment: When you've found a solution, why don't post it as an answer to your question (including screenshots)? Answering one's own question is a common procedure in GIS SE and is extremely helpful for other users. :)

Comment: You are right. I will do that. I´m fairly new to the community. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: See this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/441505/getting-all-symbols-to-render-when-using-point-displacement-in-qgis/441590#441590

Answer (score 11):

To just show another possibility: you can use [Geometry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#hard-fa-geometry-generator-symbology) and create [wedge buffers](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#wedge-buffer). The advantage is that A) you have only one symbol layer and B) you can use it to create even more complex symbols (see below).

Use this expression, where `1.7` is the size (radius) of the symbol in layer units:

```
collect_geometries(
wedge_buffer ($geometry, 90, 180, 1.7),
wedge_buffer ($geometry, 270, 180, 1.7)
)
```

To apply different colors for right and left half, use data driven override for color with this expression. To do so, expand the `Geometry Generator` entry, select `Simple Fill` underneath, go to `Fill Color` and click data driven override: the <kbd>ɛ</kbd> icon, then select `Edit...` and paste this expression (see 2nd screenshot below):

```
case
when @geometry_part_num = 1 then 'red'
else 'blue'
end
```

*Applyin Geometry Generator...*
[image]

*... and setting different colors:*
[image]

---

Based on this, you could also create complexer symbols, e.g. using this expression to create not 2, but 18 parts:

```
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach (
        generate_series(20,360,20),
        wedge_buffer ($geometry, @element, 360/array_length(generate_series(90,360,90))/4, 27)
    )
)
```

For the color, use data driven override > assistant, select `@geometry_part_num` for `source` and Values from 1 to 18 and choose a color ramp (I used pre-installed `Turbo` color ramp):

[image]

---

If you have a categorized style and only want one of the points to be styled in two colors (as mentioned in your comment), you have two options:

1. duplicate the layer and style it differently (once categorized, the other one styling just the one point with two colors)
2. double-click on the one of the catgorized point you want to style differently. When you double click it, you have a new dialog window with the symbol layers where you can make the settings as described above, see here where only the point categorized as `5` is styled differently:

[image]

Comment: For some reason it did not work for me. But it could be that I dont choose the "single symbole". I categorized my points and I only want one point two colored. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: I also have "single symbol", see my screenshot. Have you activated `Geometry Generator` and `Geometry type = Polygon` (see also screenshot)? Have you tried changing the size of `1.7`, making it larger? If you want just one point colored, you can add a condition like e.g. `if ($id = 1, ....,...)` - and what about the other points?

Comment: It is a great answer but for the scope of the question, it is quite involved.

Comment: Indeed - I just added it since OP in their comment mentioned to have found a solution, but still being interested in other solutions.

Comment: no I didnt choose "single symbole" I chose "categorized" since I only want one point of all points to be two colored. The rest of the points should be only red... I think thats why it doesnt work. I did everything like you did.
@LouisCottereau I asked if there are other solutions thats why Babel provided another solution. Thanks btw.!

Comment: I added a solution for that at the bottom of my answer, see updated answer

Comment: Thank you! But the second part with the color choosing doesnt work for me. Could you do an exact screenshot where to put the second part?
case
when @geometry_part_num = 1 then 'red'
else 'blue'
end

Comment: I added a more detailed description and a new screenshot that shows how to do it

Answer (score 9):

In QGIS you have to go to: Layer Properties > Symbology > Symbol selector > Simple Marker > scroll down and select the half circle > Rotation: 90°

For the second half circle: add another Simple Marker > scroll down and select the half circle > Rotation: 270°

End result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you have one point for which you want the red/blue semi-circles. I assume the others are to be simple circle fill points.
In order to isolate just the one point with the different style, choose 'Rule-based' as your symbol type (ie instead of 'Single symbol'). Then create your rule (depending on the particular attribute of the point in question) and apply one of the answers above (rotated half-circles or geometry generator). Then apply an 'Else' style which has the simple circle fill to apply to the remaining points.